# Why does this C# ThreadPool sometimes drop work items?

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool

```
class Program
{
    private int x = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program p = new Program();
        int a, b;
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out a, out b);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", a, b);
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            WaitCallback cb = new WaitCallback(DoSomething);

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(cb, y);
        }
    }

    public static void DoSomething(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(state);
    }
}
```

Most of the time it prints out 20 items. However, sometimes it only prints a few. Why is that? I come from a Java background and am wondering if I am making some bad assumptions about how .NET ThreadPools work.

Comment: Start by adding a Console.ReadLine() at the end-of-Main

Comment: Yes, the program is exiting (main thread finishes) before the background threads have a chance to run. (Also there is no need to instantiate a new `Program`.)

Comment: Assuming that .NET BCL code has a bug usually turns out to be false. The bus is in user code with overwhelming probability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ThreadPool is OK, it doesn't drop anything.

Most likely your program closes before the output is complete.
The ThreadPool uses background threads and they are simply aborted when the process exits.

So add something that waits, like a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of Main and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to block the program from continuing before all the threads have finished their respective tasks. After your loop, you will want to block the main thread until all the callbacks have been fired.